# loop and produce PDF in one file in itextsharp?

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I have a situation. I need to produce a report in pdf with each customer name on each pdf page. I used a user control and on the control, I have a label. I reckon that I need to use loop and when each customer id is passed, I read the customer name. Something like this:

```
 If Not customer_id Is Nothing Then
                    For Each c_id As String In customer_id
                        label1.text=rdr("customer_name")

                    Next
                End If
```

Now the problem is I can have only one customer with this logic when my pdf file is created in the page render event because whatever customer name in the label control text in the loop logic above is replaced with the last customer id's name. I need a way that I can store the html string being populated in each loop or reproduce the exact same page and append it to the current page. When the loop is over, create a pdf file for once and for all.

Any suggestion for me please?

Thanks

P.S: I stored more than just the customer name like a Gridview. But for simplicity, I just mentioned customer name.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking but I think, at this point, it isn't iTextSharp related. Since you are saying "page render event" can I assume you are talking about ASP.Net? iTextSharp only handles HTML and CSS, no GridViews or labels or anything from ASP.Net, so you need to figure that logic out first. I recommend clarifying your question and re-tagging VB.Net and ASP.Net.

Comment: I have re-tag this. @ChrisHaas yes I am using asp.net. In page render event, all the controls will rendered as html tag. So this should not be a problem with itextsharp. Do you how I can preserve the value in each loop in whatever language you use?